# Input element transitions improperly when focused, but not when selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input element which I am translating upon its X axis. When it slides into view I'd like it to be focused.

If I tell the element to focus itself - the transition jumps. If I tell the element to select itself (thus highlighting any text in itself, but also focusing) - the transition does not jump.

Why?

```js
var searchInputWrapper = $('.searchInputArea-searchInputWrapper');
var searchButton = $('.searchInputArea-searchButton');
var searchInput = $('.searchInputArea-searchInput');

searchInput.on('blur', function() {
  searchInputWrapper.removeClass('is-active').addClass('is-inactive');
  searchButton.removeClass('is-hidden');
  searchInputWrapper.addClass('is-hidden');
});

searchInput.on('focus', function() {
  console.log('searchInput on focus is ran');
  searchInputWrapper.addClass('is-active').removeClass('is-inactive');
});

$('#click1').click(function() {
  searchButton.addClass('is-hidden');
  searchInputWrapper.removeClass('is-hidden');
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    searchInput.focus();
  });
});

$('#click2').click(function() {
  searchButton.addClass('is-hidden');
  searchInputWrapper.removeClass('is-hidden');
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    searchInput.select();
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  width: 640px;
  height: 280px;
}
.flexRow {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 0;
}
.is-hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.button--icon {
  line-height: 0;
}
.button--icon--primary {
  opacity: 0.87;
}
.button--icon--primary:hover:not(.is-disabled) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.button--large {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
.searchInputArea {
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.searchInputArea-searchInputWrapper {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) 2s, background-color cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) 2s;
}
.searchInputArea-searchInputWrapper.is-active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
.searchInputArea-searchInputWrapper.is-active .searchInputArea-searchInput {
  opacity: 1;
}
.searchInputArea-searchInputWrapper.is-inactive {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 48px));
}
.searchInputArea-searchIcon,
.searchInputArea-searchButton {
  padding: 0 12px;
}
.searchInputArea-searchInput {
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 36px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) 2s;
  flex: 1;
}
.searchInputArea-searchInput::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: inherit;
}
.contentBar {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 4px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 56px;
  color: white;
  fill: white;
  background-color: #4285f4;
}
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="appBar">
  <div class="contentBar">
    <div data-region="searchInputArea" class="flexRow">
      <div class="searchInputArea flexRow">
        <div data-ui="searchInputWrapper" class="searchInputArea-searchInputWrapper flexRow is-hidden is-inactive">
          <div class="searchInputArea-searchIcon button button--icon">
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27c.98-1.14 1.57-2.62 1.57-4.23 0-3.59-2.91-6.5-6.5-6.5s-6.5 2.91-6.5 6.5 2.91 6.5 6.5 6.5c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99 1.49-1.49-4.99-5zm-6 0c-2.49 0-4.5-2.01-4.5-4.5s2.01-4.5 4.5-4.5 4.5 2.01 4.5 4.5-2.01 4.5-4.5 4.5z"></path>
              <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <input data-ui="searchInput" class="searchInputArea-searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <div data-ui="searchButton" class="searchInputArea-searchButton button button--icon button--icon--primary button--large">
          <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27c.98-1.14 1.57-2.62 1.57-4.23 0-3.59-2.91-6.5-6.5-6.5s-6.5 2.91-6.5 6.5 2.91 6.5 6.5 6.5c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99 1.49-1.49-4.99-5zm-6 0c-2.49 0-4.5-2.01-4.5-4.5s2.01-4.5 4.5-4.5 4.5 2.01 4.5 4.5-2.01 4.5-4.5 4.5z"></path>
            <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="click1">CLICK ME I AM BUGGY</button>
<button id="click2">CLICK ME I WORK FINE</button>
```